# How to make a string to a formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, formula

I've built a formula like this using the `CONCATENATE` function:

```
=CONCATENATE("=SUM('D:\Tour\", TEXT(A2,"yyy"), "\", TEXT(A2,"mmmm"), "\", TEXT(A2,"mmm"), " ", TEXT(A2,"d"), "\[", B2, ".xlsx]Sheet1'!E:E)")
```

and it returns output like the following:

> =SUM('D:\Tour\2017\February\Feb 1[11043.xlsx]Sheet1'!E:E)

Column A contains the date, and column B contains the filename.

At this point, I am copying the formula into notepad and then pasting back into Excel. Is there any way I can use the formula directly?

(I tried indirect formula but it doesn't work.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula), you can write the following VBA function:

```
Function EV(s As String) As Variant
    EV = Evaluate(s)
End Function
```

and call it from Excel:

```
=EV("=A1+B1")
```

or

```
=EV(C2)
```

<sup>There is a [second answer to that question](https://superuser.com/a/774135/175382) which doesn't involve VBA, but I was unable to get it to work.</sup>